# My CSS #wrapper style needs to be be applied to a HTML document using div

Tags: html, css

My main focus is to get my current default.htm document formatted from the #wrapper CSS I have in another folder. I cannot figure out where the error is as when I go to open my default.htm I have no formatting. 
My main focus is to get my current default.htm document style from the #wrapper CSS I have in another folder. I cannot figure out where the error is as when I go to open my default.htm I have no formatting.

```
 <!doctype html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
 <title> Avery Owen's INFO1311 Home Page </title> 
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 </head>
 <body>
 <div id="wrapper">

 <h1> Avery Owen's INFO 1311 Web Site </h1>
 <h2> Winter 2019 </h2>
 <h3> Homework Assignments</h3>
 <ul>
 <li><a href="module2/assignment2.css">Assignment 2</a></li>
 <li> Assignment 3</li>
 <li> Assignment 4</li>
 <li> Assignment 5</li>
 <li> Assignment 6</li>
 <li> Assignment 7</li>
 </ul>
 <h3> Final Project Home Page </h3>
 <h3>Important Links</h3>
 <ul>
 <li> <a href="http://blackboard.mccneb.edu">Blackboard Course Web Site </a>
 <li> <a href="http://www.mccneb.edu">Metro Web Site </a>
 <li> <a href="http://validator.w3.org">W3C HTML Validator </a>
 <li> <a href="http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/">W3C CSS Validator </a>
 </ul>
<footer><p> Created by <a href="aowen6@mail.mccneb.edu">Avery Owen </a></p></footer>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is where I am pulling from

```
body{background-color: red;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
margin: 0;
}


#wrapper{width: 900;
background-color: white;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}



header{background-color: yellow;
}


h1{font-family: Trebuchet MS, sans-serif;
color: green;
text-shadow: black;
}



h2{color: red;
margin-top: -20;
margin-left: 30;
}



h3{color: blue;
text-shadow: yellow;
}



footer{background-color: gray;
color: blue;
text-align: right;
font-size: .8em;
font-style: italic;
}
```

Comment: not sure what you mean? You wanna apply same CSS on this page as you have in another?

Comment: Where do you include the reference to the stylesheet in the HTML?

Comment: @AndreFigueiredo I want to put the CSS style into my html document

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reference the stylesheet in the header of the page inside `<head>` tags.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="folder/style.css" >
```

Change the href path to the path of your stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend using a text and source code editor such as [Atom](https://atom.io/), [Sublime text](https://www.sublimetext.com/) or [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) if you are not doing so already. You can simply open up the files together in windows inside the editor which is very convenient. In your HTML code you must insert a link tag to get the code from the .css file, and insert it inside your head tags:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
<!-- the href format is folder_name/file_name.css
```

,the folder must be stored in the same hierarchical level in your directory as the default.html file you are linking it to in this case -->

Here is how the format should look inside your .css file

```
 /********************ID SELECTORS*******************/
        /*EXAMPLE OF FORMAT*/
        #wrapper{
          width: 15em;
          border: 1px solid #333;
          box-shadow: 8px 8px 5px #444;
          padding: 8px 12px;
          background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, #fff, #ddd 40%, #ccc);
        }
```